# How to get the last inserted ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the last inserted ID from MySQL database in PHP and I was wondering what would be the best way to do it?

I am currently using this kind of solution, but there has to be a better and safer way. So would someone please help me? Thanks

```
Some insert statement...

 $query = "SELECT MAX(aid) FROM asset";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                                    {
                                    $pickassssult= $row['MAX(aid)'];


                                    }
```

Comment: This has been asked a lot. Did you try to search your exact same question before posting it? i just [did](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+get+the+last+inserted+ID%3F+[mysql]+[php]), with the exact same question, same tags. and not surprisingly, the same answers ;-)

Comment: Don't scold the newbies! :-) Until an admin links the question to the "proper answer" it's a valid one. People don't ask for help, if they don't need it; be nice, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a function called:

```
 mysql_insert_id();
```

more info
http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

See the manual: [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL command:`last_insert_id()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the insert id by calling the mysql_insert_id() function. See [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_insert_id()`. Hovewer, it's not absolutely safe. Here is a [manual](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)