# Getting an ID for the last inserted value

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the unique ID for the most recently added value to the database.  I tried using LastInsertID bu I believe this is not compatible with MySQL (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO discussion_links (link_url, link_title, link_source, publish_date, link_side, img_link) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$sth=$db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($_POST['OP_link_url'], $_POST['OP_title'], $_POST['OP_source'], $_POST['OP_pub_date'], $_POST['OP_disc_side'], $_POST['OP_img_url']));
$op_link_id = $sth->$db->lastInsertID();
```

Here I get the error: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PDO could not be converted to string

I also tried doing that last line as:

```
$op_link_id = $sth->fetch(PDO::lastInsertID);
```

And

```
$temp = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$temp_op_link_id = $temp['link_id'];
```

But neither one worked (got some SQLState General Error 2053).

Thanks,

Comment: $id = $this->db->insert_id();  try this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last inserted ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008656/how-to-get-the-last-inserted-id)

Comment: @dude, thanks for the quick response.  I tried doing the above right after in the PHP code and got the server error: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context.  I need to get that ID to use it in another query right afterwards.

Comment: i meant to use only the insert_id()

Comment: @Hamish, I thought we should not be using mysql_XXX commands but rather PDO?

Comment: SELECT MAX(ID) AS LastID FROM tablename... u can fetch usin the query too... but @xdazz has given the solution i guess in the answer column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lastInsertID()` should be called on PDO instance.

```
$op_link_id = $sth->$db->lastInsertID();
```

Should be

```
$op_link_id = $db->lastInsertID();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$op_link_id = $db->lastInsertID();
```